# What is the optimal size in the finite axiom of symmetry?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Freiling's [axiom of symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiling%27s_axiom_of_symmetry) states that if you assign to each real number $x$ a countable set $A_x\subset\mathbb{R}$, then there should be two reals $x,y$ for which $x\notin A_y$ and $y\notin A_x$.

This principle turns out to be equivalent to the failure of the continuum hypothesis, a fact on which I spoke today at the CUNY math graduate student colloquium, [Freiling's axiom of symmetry or, throwing darts at the real line](http://jdh.hamkins.org/freilings-axiom-of-symmetry-graduate-student-colloquium-april-2016/).

Informally, the axiom asserts that if you have attached to each element $x$ of a large set $\mathbb{R}$ a certain comparatively small subset $A_x$, then there should be two independent points $x,y$, meaning that neither is in the set attached to the other.

At the conclusion of the talk I had assigned an exercise to the audience to prove the finite analogue of the axiom:

**The finite axiom of symmetry.** For each finite number $k$ there is a sufficiently large  finite number $n$ such that for any set $X$ of size $n$ and any assignment $x\mapsto A_x$ of elements $x\in X$ to subsets $A_x\subset X$ of size $k$, there are elements $x,y\in X$ such that $x\notin A_y$ and $y\notin A_x$. (See [my blog post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/the-finite-axiom-of-symmetry/).)

That is, for any concept of smallness $k$, there is a large size $n$ such that whenever we attach a small subset $A_x$ to each element $x$ of a large set $X$, then there are two independent elements, neither of which are in the set attached to the other.

Here is one way to see it. Suppose we are given a finite number $k$. Let $n$ be any number larger than $k^2+k$. Consider any set $X$ of size $n$ and any assignment $x\mapsto A_x$ of elements $x\in X$ to subsets $A_x\subset X$ of size at most $k$. Let $x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$ be any $k+1$ many elements of $X$. The union $\bigcup_{i\leq k} A_{x_i}$ has size at most $(k+1)k=k^2+k$, and so by the choice of $n$ there is some element $y\in X$ not in any $A_{x_i}$. Since $A_y$ has size at most $k$, there must be some $x_i$ not in $A_y$. So $x_i\notin  A_y$ and $y\notin A_{x_i}$, and we have fulfilled the desired conclusion.

It seems unlikely to me that this argument gives the optimal bound on the size of $n$, since first of all it is simply the first argument I thought about, and secondly, the argument gives more than is necessary, since it shows with $n>k^2+k$ that we can find at least one of the pair of independent elements inside any $k+1$ size subset of $X$ and the other outside. So perhaps we might hope for a smaller bound.  MathOverflow is overrun with talented finite combinatoricists, and I am hoping they can help me find the optimal size:

**Question.** What is the optimal size of $n$ as a function of $k$?

That is, what is the smallest size $n$ for which the conclusion of the finite axiom of symmetry holds for assignments in a set of size $n$ to subsets of size $k$?

Please feel free to post better bounds than I have given, even if you don't know it is optimal. Or perhaps there is an easy argument for the optimal bound.

Comment: Or perhaps the combinatoricists already have a standard name for what I am calling the finite axiom of symmetry? If so, what is it?

Comment: Is it assumed that the two elements $x$, $y$, are distinct? Say $k=1$, and $n=3>k^2+k$, $X=\{a,b,c\}$, $a\mapsto\{b\}$, $b\mapsto\{c\}$, $c\mapsto\{a\}$. Then $a$ is not in $A_b$, but $b$ is in $A_a$; $b$ is not in $A_c$, but $c$ is in $A_b$; $c$ is not in $A_a$, but $a$ is in $A_c$.

Comment: My proof does not assume that $x$ and $y$ are distinct, as your example shows. Namely, in your example we can take $x=a$ and $y=a$ to fulfill the axiom. In the infinite cases that inspire the question, we may always assume $x\in A_x$ without loss, since this doesn't change the size, and in that case, one can equivalently assume $x\neq y$. But in the finite case of course this changes the size. Feel free to post an answer for the case where you interpret the principle as requiring $x\neq y$. This may amount to changing $k$ to $k+1$.

Comment: That is, if you want to insist that $x\neq y$, then my argument shows that $n>(k+1)(k+2)$ suffices, since for any assignment, we modify it by insisting $x\in A_x$, which may make the sizes $k+1$, and then apply my argument. But in this case, we will have $x\neq y$ in order to have independence.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, everyone! I knew I could *count* on the MO combinatoricists!

Comment: I'm a Number Theorist.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't mean any offense---I had just noticed that all three users who posted have the combinatorics tag prominent on their user profiles.  In your case, it is your second tag after number theory.

Comment: No offense taken – in my dreams, I'm a combinatorialist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given $k$, let $X=\{1,2,\dots,2k\}$. We must have $1$ in $A_1$, else we could take $x=y=1$. We may assume $A_1=\{1,2,\dots,k\}$. So $r$ is not in $A_1$ for $r=k+1,k+2,\dots,2k$. So we must have $1$ in $A_r$ for $r=k+1,k+2,\dots,2k$. That is, $1$ must be in $k+1$ of the sets $A_r$ (since it's also in $A_1$). But there's nothing special about $1$, so each of the elements $1,2,\dots,2k$ must be in $k+1$ of the sets $A_r$. But there isn't room for $2k(k+1)$ elements in $2k$ sets of size $k$. Therefore, if $n=2k$, there must be $x$ and $y$ (possibly $x=y$) with $x$ not in $A_y$, and $y$ not in $A_x$.

If $n=2k-1$, let $A_1=\{1,2,\dots,k\}$, $A_2=\{2,3,\dots,k+1\}$, and so on, to $A_{2k-1}=\{2k-1,1,2,\dots,k-1\}$, then there are no $x$ and $y$ with $x$ not in $A_y$ and $y$ not in $A_x$.

Comment: Great! It seems like this solves it. Could you translate this solution for the case where we insist $x\neq y$?

Comment: Looks like @bof has done this.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we have $|A|=n\in\mathbb N,$ and $A_x\in\binom Ak$ for each $x\in A,$ such that for any two distinct elements $x,y\in A,$ either $x\in A_y$ or $y\in A_x.$ Define a [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)) $T$ on the vertex-set $V(T)=A$ so that $xy\in E(T)\implies y\in A_x.$ Then the score (outdegree) of each vertex is $\le k.$ Since the sum of all the scores is $\binom n2=\frac{n(n-1)}2,$ the average score is $\frac{n-1}2,$ whence $\frac{n-1}2\le k,$ i.e., $n\le2k+1.$

That is, if $|A|\ge2k+2,$ and if $|A_x|\le k$ for each $x\in A,$ then there exist two distinct elements $x,y\in A$ with $x\notin A_y$ and $y\notin A_x.$

On the other hand, it is quite easy to construct a tournament on $2k+1$ vertices in which each vertex has score $k;$ namely, put the vertices on a circle, and draw directed edges from each vertex to the next $k$ vertices clockwise.

**P.S.** Replacing "distinct" with "not necessarily distinct" amounts to imposing the condition $x\in A_x$ which amounts to replacing $k$ with $k-1.$

Answer (score 3):

This seems really easy? Let $A \subseteq X^2$ be the set of all $(x,y)$ such that $y \in A_x$, and let $A^r$ be the reflection of this across the main diagonal. You are asking whether $A\cup A^r = X^2$. Suppose, for a contradiction, that $n \ge 2k$ and that $A\cup A^r = X^2$. Then $A$ must certainly contain the diagonal of $X^2$, so by the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion, we have

$|X^2| = |A\cup A^r| = |A| + |A^r| - |A \cap A^r| \le 2nk - n < n^2 = |X^2|,$

a contradiction. On the other hand, if $n \le 2k-1$ then we can take $X = \mathbb{Z}/n$ and $A_x = \{x, x+1, ..., x+k-1\}$, so that $A = \{(x,y) \mid y-x \in \{0, ..., k-1\}\}$.